# How to implement Try Catch Finally Statement with form input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch, finally

I'm trying to use this to create a message that states "Please enter a number" when you hit submit on a form and there's no number in the input for "If you would like to state a specific amount type it in the box below". It's doing absolutely nothing, so I don't know what's going on. I'm still in school and this is my first class with JavaScript so I would appreciate any help you can give.

Here is the JavaScript portion:

````
```
// test page form exception code - Chapter 4
function verifyFormCompleteness() {
    var specificAmountBox = document.getElementById("specificamount");
    var completeEntry = true;
    var messageElement = document.getElementById("message");
    var messageHeadElement = document.getElementById("messageHead");
    var validity = true;
    var messageText = "";
      try {
            if (specificAmountBox.value == "" || specificAmountBox.value == null){
            window.alert = "Please enter a number in the specific amount box";
            }
      }
      catch(message) {
           validity = false;
           messageText = message;
           specificAmountBox.value = ""; // removes bad entry from input box
      }
      finally {
           completeEntry
           messageElement.innerHTML = messageText;
           messageHeadElement.innerHTML = "";
           alert("This is happening in the finally block");
      }
      if (validity = true) {
           return submit;
      }
}
```
````

Here is the HTML portion:

````
```If you would like to state a specific amount type it in the box below:<br>
            <input type="number" id="specificamount" name="specificamount">
            <h1 id="messageHead"></h1>
            <p id="message"></p>
            <br>
            <br>
```
````

Comment: @AluanHaddad okay, just did. That's as good as I can do.

Comment: @AluanHaddad There, happy now?

Comment: It's my first time using this site, so I didn't know how to do it. Nice job deleting your comments.